# Lecture Courses on Differential Geometry

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, soft-question, online-resources

I am looking for a first course on differential geometry. I want to use lecture notes as I often find these an easier way to get into the subject. I am not looking for book recommendations.

Does anyone have a suggestions for good, free online course materials (lectures AND questions preferably with solutions) for a standard course in differential geometry?

Comment: I get a lot when googling "lecture notes differential geometry", or "exercises differential geometry".

Comment: Yes but I am asking for a recommendation for a good one. You may get a lot of results but i have looked myself before and some are not that good/difficult to learn from

Comment: @DietrichBurde For instance there is the part iii cambridge dg notes but i find that too dense

Comment: May be then you should look for something in part II... what do you want to learn? By "a standard course in differential geometry?" you mean of what level?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik same material as in part iii haha but more like 120 pages instead of 60 pages in length

Comment: do you want to write down explicitly what are that? I do not want to google to find out :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik these dont look right https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~gpp24/dgnotes/dg.pdf. I want an abstract courses as Im not interested in curves and surfaces

Comment: Then you might want to see https://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/rossmann/Differential%20Geometry%20book_files/Diffgeo.pdf

Comment: I suggest reading do Carmo's book Riemannian Geometry. If you do not want to buy one, get it from your library. It will be better than what you will find online.

Comment: I agree with @MoisheCohen You should atleast read chapter 0 even if you find it difficult.. It is only ~30 pages... Once you understand that ~30 pages, I am sure you will get enough motivation to read further in that book...